# OpenCV detect if image file is colour prior to loading

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I know you can use imread to get an image into a numpy array.

```
cv2.imread(path,0)
```

Loads a greyscale image and...

```
cv2.imread(path,1)
```

Loads a colour one.

I can call the second one on a greyscale image and it returns a shape (y,x,3) hence it is still in the format of a colour image even though it has none.

Is there a function in opencv to detect what colour format the file is in so I can call the right imread function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread

Looking at the list of flags available "-1" (<0), in the second input parameter should do what you're asking for. 
Try to use `cv2.imread(path,-1)`

Answer (score 2):

I assume your are using Python since you mentioned numpy.

You can´t check which type an image has before loading it.

The easiest solution to guarantee that you have a grayscale image, would be to use something like this (if you want to always have a grayscale):

```
        if len(im.shape) > 2:
            im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.cv.CV_RGB2GRAY)
```

Comment: I wish to have 2 routes for the logic based on whether the image is colour or not. Using M4rtini's answer I can get either a bw or colour image and then I can use the shape property to work out if it has colour or not.

Comment: It seems like i missunderstood your problem. However the Answer might help others, so i think it is best to leave it here.

Comment: Combining your answers gives the solution. :)